# UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: android, react-native, apk, release

**On trying to create release apk from my react native app. 
I am getting this following error:**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: 
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 

/User/TestApp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
/drawable-hdpi
/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_dist_views_assets_backicon.png
```

Debug apk , builds fine. But I'm stuck in making release apk.

> reactnavigationstack_dist_views_assets_backicon : 
>   I cannot figure out this back icon issue.

Cay somebody point this issue?

Thanks you for your reading .

Comment: does this file have a read and write permission ?

Comment: @TejasPandya that icon is autogenerated by reactnativegation stack I guess.
On trying to build the release, it comes from nowhere and says access denied.

Comment: i dont know much about `react` but after error . go to `User/TestApp/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
/drawable-hdpi
/` and check file permission

Comment: @TejasPandya Thanks brother... but actually the issue was duplicate assets issues thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this issue is due to duplicate assets issues in android folder. 
Verify once again to remove duplicates.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You have duplicate build folders. One is App module and other is project module. Please do the following steps to overcome this issue:

1. Exit Android Studio, If running
2. Remove App module build folder and it's all contents
3. Remove Project build folder and it's all contents
4. Rebuild the project

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Delete directories `/build` and `app/build`.

GL

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error once updating Gradle, i needed to go into my projects module file (which contains libs, src files) and delete the build folder, once i did this and rebuilt all was good

Answer (score 1):

In my case was the Google Drive sinc app that was locking files. I decided to pause Google Drive sinc whenever i start programming and it solved all problems